# How to avoid timeout (net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED 8mins) when uploading files with axios post method?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, http, nginx, axios

I'm doing some big file (10GB+) uploading so what I did is slicing the file to some `3MB chunks` and then upload them. It works fine until I got a really bad network scenario (cannot finished uploading a chunk with 8mins). The browser(chrome) gave me an `net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED` error and after checking on the Internet it basically means timeout. I changed timeout setting for this api in Nginx to 99999, it will not give me 504 error (meaning nginx didn't cut the connection because of timeout) but the maximum time for me to upload a slice is 8mins. I think this problem is caused by browser itself so I checked the browser concole. The thing is the network page shows that "uploadSlice " used 8mins to initial connection! But the progress bar still going so I have no idea how to solve this.
Here is that error screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q6Ed.png)

Here is my code for the upload slice part. (I use axios and a post method to send chunk)

```
 request(formData,cancel) {
      let uid = formData.get("uid");
      let lastLoad = 0;

      //formData contains file's chunk and other info
      return this.$http.post("/file/uploadSlice", formData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        
        //this part is using for progress bar calculation
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          let loadThisTime = progressEvent.loaded - lastLoad;
          lastLoad = progressEvent.loaded;
          this.$store.dispatch("updateState/addCompleteNessAsync",[uid,loadThisTime]);
        },
        cancelToken: cancel
      });
    },
```

And here is my setting for this api in Nginx:
(in default.conf)

```
location /api/file/uploadSlice {
                proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:9090/file/uploadSlice/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
                proxy_read_timeout 99999;
                proxy_connect_timeout 99999;
                proxy_send_timeout 99999;

        }
```

in nginx.conf:

```
...
http{
    ...
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    client_body_buffer_size 5m;
    client_header_timeout 120s;
    ...

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```